# Why is GRUB working on one computer but not the other?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub, firmware

I've installed Arch Linux on to a USB stick.  The stick is partitioned as GPT, and there are two partitions - an EFI boot partition, formatted as FAT32, and a boot partition formatted as EXT4.

When I insert the USB stick into my (Lenovo Z50-70) laptop, it boots to the GRUB boot menu, and everything is fine.  However, when I try it on an older machine - a Viglen omnino, I get a black screen with the word

```
GRUB _
```

on it, where the underscore after `GRUB` is blinking.  If I press any key, this disappears and the computer boots into Windows 7.

Here is the BIOS boot menu for the Viglen, together with all the options I've selected:

```
Boot menu type            [Advanced]
Boot Drive Order          [SanDisk Cruzer E]
                          [SATA: WDC WD3200]
                          [SATA: Optiarc DV]
                          [IBA GE Slot 00C8]
Boot to Optical Devices   [Enable]
Boot to Removable Devices [Enable]
Boot to Network           [Enable]
USB Boot                  [Enable]   -- Note: changing this causes boot to Windows
Boot USB Devices First    [Disable]  -- Note: changing this setting does nothing
UEFI Boot                 [Enable]
```

The SanDisk Cruzer is the USB drive I am trying to boot into.  I think it must be a BIOS problem because it's all working fine on my computer.  The USB stick boots in UEFI/GPT mode, which should be fine on the Viglen, since it has a UEFI Boot option (see above).  My laptop is 64 bit, while the Viglen is 64 Architecture capable.